# How to do a netstat that will only filter based on pid

Tags: linux, grep, process, netstat

How can I have the following command below just show/filter based on the PID's I'm looking for?

```
sudo netstat -lp --inet
```

The results come back as this

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:1508                  *:*                     LISTEN      7609/kodi.bin   
tcp        0      0 *:38565                 *:*                     LISTEN      18079/Plex Plug-in 
tcp        0      0 *:59240                 *:*                     LISTEN      24656/Plex Plug-in 
tcp        0      0 *:46185                 *:*                     LISTEN      18427/Plex Plug-in 
tcp        0      0 *:netbios-ssn           *:*                     LISTEN      989/smbd        
tcp        0      0 *:34061                 *:*                     LISTEN      25066/Plex Plug-in 
tcp        0      0 *:59310                 *:*                     LISTEN      18190/Plex Plug-in 
tcp        0      0 *:50383                 *:*                     LISTEN      18243/Plex Plug-in 
tcp        0      0 *:48336                 *:*                     LISTEN      18081/Plex Plug-in 
tcp        0      0 *:32400                 *:*                     LISTEN      17990/Plex Media Se
tcp        0      0 *:1136                  *:*                     LISTEN      7609/kodi.bin   
tcp        0      0 localhost:http-alt      *:*                     LISTEN      21149/syncthing
```

I just want the lines with the **PID 7609/kodi.bin** in them.  so the final output would look like the example below.

```
tcp        0      0 *:1508                  *:*                     LISTEN      7609/kodi.bin
tcp        0      0 *:1136                  *:*                     LISTEN      7609/kodi.bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netstat` itself does not support such filtering.

You probably have to do something like:

```
sudo netstat -lp --inet | grep " $pid/"
```

Comment: thanks worked great.
sudo netstat -lp --inet | grep "$7609/"